# How to create a name with as desired while reading for loop

Tags: jquery

I am reading  a JSON and construction a table from it ,
during this process i am reading an inner array "**Video_details**"

While reading the inner array i need to take only first **3** elements and if there are more 
elements i need to put **... (3 dots )**

so that it looks like (3 dots after one two three)

```
Test 001    xxx   one two three ...    SERTVal


var aajxresponse = {
  "tag_video_details": [{
    "video_id": "369",
    "tag_name": "three",
    "video_name": "test 001",
    "video_file": "xxx",
    "Video_details": [
      "one",
      "two",
      "three",
      "four",
      "five",
      "six",
      "seven",
      "eight",
      "nine",
      "ten"
    ]

  }]
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  updatetable(aajxresponse);

});

function updatetable(aajxresponse) {
  var html = '<tr class="existingvideos">\
            <th width="20%">ID</th>\n\
            <th width="35%">Course</th>\n\
            <th width="30%">Name</th>\n\
            <th width="15%">SERT</th>\n\
        </tr>';
  var span = '<span class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-circle"></span> ';
  var v = aajxresponse.tag_video_details;
  for (var i = 0; i < v.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr video-id="' + v[i].video_id + '"  class="newvideos exercises-add-table-content">\
                             <td>' + capitalise(v[i].video_name) + '</td>\n\
                            <td><a href="' + v[i].video_file + '" target="_blank">' + v[i].video_file.split('/').pop() + '</a></td>\n';
    var vd = v[i].Video_details;
    html += '<td>\n';
    for (var j = 0; j < vd.length; j++) {
      if(j<3)
        {
      html += span.split("</span>").join(vd[j] + "</span>");
      }
    }
    html += '</td>\n';
    html += '<td>\n\
<i class="fa fa-check">SERTVal</i>\n\
</td>\n\
</tr>';
  }
  $("#videosfromtagstable tbody").html(html);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/326/

Comment: Not really sure what your confusing, mostly irrelevant to the question, code is meant to do, but you can use `.slice(0,2)` before the loop or you can use `.. j < (vd.length < 3 ? vd.length : 3)` in the for or `Math.min`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you edit that text, simply add the condition for when the count is greater than 3.  So where you have this:

```
if(j < 3) {
    html += span.split("</span>").join(vd[j] + "</span>");
}
```

Add this:

```
else {
    html += span.split("</span>").join('...' + "</span>");
    break;
}
```

The `break` is there so that the condition happens only once, rather than for every additional element in the loop.  Once the `'...'` is added the loop should exit because the remaining elements aren't needed.

There are, I imagine, a number of ways to accomplish the same thing.  This suggestion is simply in keeping with the logic you already have, which you could refactor all you like once it's working and tested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a CSS solution, then this [one](http://jsfiddle.net/cod7ceho/328/) isn't so bad. Add your text with no spans:

```
for (var j = 0; j < vd.length; j++) {
  html += vd[j] + " ";
}
```

Then some CSS tweaks with `text-overflow` and `max-width`:

```
td.names {
  max-width: 120px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Although it may not show the first 3 items every time (due to the length of the 3 items), it will give you a fixed width to keep the page looking consistent.